# becomeFirstResponder() does not work

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I'm currently trying to create a to do app similar to **Apple Reminders**. Right now, when I add a new task by clicking on a `UIButton`, a new cell containing a `UITextfield` is created and assigned as the first responder. However, when I do this, the keyboard shows up as expected, but there is no cursor nor can I edit. When I click on the textfield again, I can edit as expected.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
@IBAction func addTask(sender: UIBarButtonItem)
{

    // Add a new task
    let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: tasks.count, inSection: 0)
    let task = Task(name: "")!
    tasks.append(task)
    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Bottom)
    let cellIdentifier = "TaskTableViewCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: newIndexPath) as! TaskTableViewCell


    let db_Task = PFObject(className: "Task")
    db_Task["TaskName"] = ""
    db_Task["Completed"] = false
    db_Task["group"] = getGroupId()
    db_Task.saveInBackgroundWithBlock
        {(success: Bool, error:  NSError?) -> Void in
            print("Object has been saved.")
    }
    cell.nameLabel.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: Is nameLabel your textField? Just thought of the name...

Answer (score 1):

```
tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Bottom)
let cellIdentifier = "TaskTableViewCell"
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: newIndexPath) as! TaskTableViewCell
```

You can't get the inserted cell by 'dequeue' method. Never call this method out of `cellForIndexPath`. You should do it like this after insert:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForIndexPath(indexPath)
```

Comment: Once I do this, I can only do
    cell.textLabel.becomeFirstResponder()

and it still doesn't work

Comment: @KennyTao Did you delete the original next two lines after insert?

Comment: I've figured it out. I had to set my cell as my custom cell class name, and your advice worked perfectly! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
self.view.endEditing
```

Answer (score 0):

BecomeFirstResponder should be called on the object you want to focus. In this case, `cell.nameLabel` is wrong object.

You should call `cell.[your_text_field]` instead.

Comment: nameLabel is the name of my textfield, should have clarified